# Kotlin reactive channels: Nested publisher won't start after parent completes?

Tags: kotlin, reactive-programming, kotlinx.coroutines

In Kotlin 1.3.11 and v1.0.1 of `kotlinx-coroutines-reactive`, I've found that when a `Publisher<Publisher<T>>` completes before `consumeEach` is called on some of its inner Publishers, these inner Publishers don't execute at all when they are eventually started. Is this expected? Consider for example:

```
publish {
    send(publish<Unit> {
        // delay(1E6); // optionally try to wait a long time to verify it's not run at all
        println("inner finished")
    })
    // send(launch { println("inner finished") }) // note: this isn't a problem for launch
    println("outer finished")
}
    .consumeEach {
        yield()
        println("try to start inner")
        it.consumeEach {  }
        // it.join() // try this when sending `launch {}`
    }
```

Which results in

```
outer finished
try to start inner

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Is my gut on the right track that this has something to do with `ProducerScope`s (since `Publisher` is scoped by these, cf. [docs](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/reactive/kotlinx-coroutines-reactive))?